# cloud function not working on emulator when internet is slow

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch a document using cloud function and it works smooth always but when I am  on low speed internet, it seems to not work.

Kindly note, this is not a cold restart issue as my mobile is getting records from same cloud function. On the other hand the emulator on my laptop is not getting any records from cloud function but is getting multiple firestore records, so definetly not internet issue.

```
try {
      HttpsCallable callable =
          FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('onGetNewQuestion');
      final result = await callable({
        'mytext': 'A message sent from a client device',
      });

      if (result.data != null) {
        if (result.data['code'] == 200) {
          // ignore: prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings
          log.d("Question recieved: " + result.data['data'].toString());
          var data = result.data['data'].cast<String, dynamic>();

          QuestionModel question = QuestionModel(
              description: data['description'],
              emoji: data['emoji'],
              id: data['id']);
          return question;
        }
      }
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (error) {
      log.e(error.code);
      log.e(error.details);
      log.e(error.message);
    } catch (error) {
      log.e(error.toString());
    }
```

Below is my cloud function for the above flutter code

```
export const onGetNewQuestion = functions.https // }) //   enforceAppCheck: true, // .runWith({
  .onCall(async (data, context) => {

    console.log('Inside onGetNewQuestion');

    const MAX_QUESTIONS = 35;

    var db = admin.firestore();
    var questions = db.collection('questions');

    //fetching random number from database
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * MAX_QUESTIONS);
    console.log('Random number: ', random);

    //Select random question from database
    const qRef = questions.where('id', '>=', random).limit(1);

    return await qRef
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        console.log('QuerySnapshot Found: ', querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
        return {
          code: 200,
          status: 'success',
          message: 'Question fetched successfully',
          data: querySnapshot.docs[0].data(),
        };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
        return {
          code: 500,
          status: 'error',
          message: 'Internal Server Error',
        };
      });
  });
```

I am getting the below error:

[image]

Comment: this issue is probably related to this https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/7070  add your case there and steps to reproduce maybe you will get some solution.